# How can I check if a command is in a group in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a help command that uses the following loop to find all the commands in a given cog.

```
for command in self.bot.get_cog(cog).walk_commands():
    if not command.hidden:
        emb.add_field(name=f"`{command.name}`", value=command.help, inline=False)
```

This does not distinguish which commands are subcommands (commands of a [group](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Group)).
What I want is a way to distinguish which which commands are groups, and which (sub)commands belong to which group.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWXe5.png) of what I DO NOT want (which is the current behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`parent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command.parent) attribute of a [`command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command) which will return the `group` or `None` if there is no `group`. Example:

```py
for command in self.bot.get_cog(cog).walk_commands():
    print(f"`{command.name}` `{command.parent}`")
```